# How to inspect the internet of a document.createElement('form').submit()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Assumed I have a code like this:

```
    var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
    mapForm.target ="_top";
    mapForm.method = "POST";
    mapForm.action = myurl;

    var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
    mapInput.type = "hidden";
    mapInput.name = "fileName";
    mapInput.value = `${fileName}`;
    mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
    document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
    mapForm.submit();
```

So it will trigger a download, but the Chrome DevTool did not catch that. I want to print the data from that action.

Comment: You should see it in the Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: Make sure you have Network->Preserve log checked in the DevTools preferences. Otherwise you lose the network tab when it reloads.

Comment: I can't because this behavior will open a new tab, and close it immediately

Comment: If you want to debug it, don't use the new tab.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the Preserve log is checked.

Comment: @Barmar it's not my code, and the request failed with using postman, so I want to debug it with Chrome Dev tool.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. If the tab closes immediately, there's no way to watch it in DevTools.